# Is it possible to add some meta information to Google Tasks?

Tags: google-tasks

I'd like to add some meta information to Google Tasks when creating a new task via API, is it possible? All I can see is a "notes" field which can be read by users, it's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

If you mean adding some custom metadata attached to a Task, not to be seen by users, that's not currently possible.

Here are all the fields in a `Task`, and as you can see, the kind of field you are asking for is not currently present: [Task resource](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks).

#### Feature Request:

A feature request related to this has been previously filed in Issue Tracker:

- [Provide means of inserting hidden 'meta-data' to tasks](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757064)

I'd suggest you to click the star on the top-left in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.